# Setting FQDN with external domain name

Tags: centos7, fqdn

I have a Centos 7 server which has tens of domain names and IPs.

The IP addresses are pointing to my server.

Each domain name is pointing to its own IP via A record.

I want to configure my FQDN in order to install **Postfix**.

`/etc/hostname` contains `myproject.localdomain`

`/etc/hosts` contains:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Command `hostname` returns:

```
myproject.localdomain
```

`hostname -f` returns:

```
localhost
```

domainname returns (none)

Do I have to choose a real domain purchased and prepend to it the hostname like this:

```
ip    hotname.domainame    hostname
```

Comment: That is always a good thing  but you can leave it as it is

Answer (score 0):

Method 1)

You do not define your server's hostname or FQDN using the **/etc/hosts** file

You could edit **/etc/hostname** file and fill in your hostname and save the file. That would be just a part of the process

Then on CentOS 7 you have **hostnamectl** command:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname host.domain.tld --static
```

Method 2)

Use **nmtui** tool by issuing **nmtui** on a ssh console or directly to the server's console. Select **Edit a Connection** then go go down with the arrow keys and select *Set system hostname* and there you set the hostname.